# __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'bar'

Tags: python, typeerror, keyword-argument

What seems like a simple pattern for allowing a variable number of positional arguments along with a defaulted named arg doesn't work.
I think I can overcome this by using `**kwargs`, but is there something more straightforward I am doing wrong?

Why doesn't this work?

```
class Foo(obect):
    """Baffling"""
    def __init__(self, bar=None, *args):
        pass

foo = Foo(1) #works
foo = Foo(1, bar=2) # explodes

----> 1 foo = Foo(1, bar='baz')
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'bar'
```

How is the above code passing a duplicate `bar` keyword argument?

Comment: Because you're passing `1` *and* `'baz'` as `bar`. You can't "skip" to `*args` by providing a named argument later on.

Comment: 1 has been assigned to bar, so you can't assign bar again in the arguments list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named arguments can be passed both by position and by name:

```
>>> def foo(a):
...     print(a)
...
>>> foo(1)
1
>>> foo(a=2)
2
```

If you pass positional and keyword arguments, they get assigned in order. In your case, 1 gets assigned to the first positional argument (`bar`), then `bar=2` assigns the the argument named `bar`. Thus, both assign to the name `bar`, creating a conflict.

---

You can pass additional arguments *after* your named one:

```
>>> def foo(bar=None, *args):
...    print('args=%r, bar=%r' % (args, bar))
...
... foo(2, 1)  # bar=2, *args=(1,)
args=(1,), bar=2
```

In Python3, you can also make your parameter keyword only:

```
>>> def foo(*args, bar=None):
...    print('args=%r, bar=%r' % (args, bar))
...
... foo(1, bar=2)
args=(1,), bar=2
```

This also works when you do not take any variadic arguments:

```
>>> def foo(*, bar=None):
...    print('args=%r, bar=%r' % ('undefined', bar))
...
... foo(bar=2)
args='undefined', bar=2
>>> foo(1, bar=2)
TypeError: foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 positional argument (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

In Python2, only `**kwargs` is allowed after `*args`. You can emulate named parameters by popping them from `kwargs`:

```
>>> def foo(*args, **kwargs):
...    bar = kwargs.pop("bar")
...    print('args=%r, bar=%r' % (args, bar))
...
... foo(1, bar=2)
args=(1,), bar=2
```

If you want named-only parameters *without* variadic positional and named parameters, you must raise errors yourself:

```
>>> def foo(*args, **kwargs):
...    bar = kwargs.pop('bar')
...    if args or kwargs:
...        raise TypeError
...    print('args=%r, bar=%r' % ('undefined', bar))
...
... foo(bar=2)
args='undefined', bar=2
>>> foo(1, bar=2)
TypeError
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, named attributes are used after non-named (like `*args`). So you should change your `__init__` as:

`def __init__(self, *args, bar=None):`

Here is the example:

```
class Foo(object):
    """Baffling"""
    def __init__(self, *args, bar=None):
        self.bar = bar

foo = Foo(1, bar=2) # explodes
foo.bar
```

Will return:

`Out[...]: 2`

---

P.S. Anyway it is not a good idea to mix `*args`, `**kwargs` and named attributes. I recommend you to avoid it.

Comment: note that this is python3 only - python2 doesn't support named arguments after `*args` and/or `**kwargs`.

Comment: Yeah, this produces a syntax error in python2, where sadly I'm constrained to work ATM. This was my first instinct. I'm glad its at least fixed in python3